# Building Custom Query with filters in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to make a custom query in django based on some filters located in the template. Should be something similar with the [View tickets section from Django official website](https://code.djangoproject.com/query)

My template should have some inputs for predefined columns in the Filter section and based on the given values should filter the results.

[image: see capture here]

I found some topics related to Q objects, but I'm not sure how to build the queries based on the values from UI.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Q objects is use for SQL OR and AND
e.g
Select * From Country Where Country_Name LIKE "India" OR Country_Name LIKE "Pakistan"

Answer (score 1):

Q objects is use for SQL OR and AND e.g

`Select * From Country Where Country_Name LIKE "India" OR Country_Name LIKE "Pakistan"`

```
Q(question__startswith='Who') | Q(question__startswith='What')
```

This is equivalent to the following SQL WHERE clause:

```
WHERE question LIKE 'Who%' OR question LIKE 'What%'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Answer (score 0):

We've implemented a query builder, akin to what you're suggesting, for the django admin over at [django-advanced-filters](https://github.com/modlinltd/django-advanced-filters).

You can probably copy paste the form/s and related templates for a similar effect outside of the admin.